console log results adding to each other, rather than printing separately
I have a function that works, and it gives me the correct return when I only use one consol.log statement. But as soon as I add 2 or more console.log statements when calling my function, it will add the printed return values together rather than print them individually. I do not want this.
Ran the function


let sum = 0;
const scores = [];

function getAverage(scores) {
  for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    sum += scores[i];
  }
  return (sum / scores.length)
}

console.log(getAverage([92, 88, 12, 77, 57, 100, 67, 38, 97, 89]));
console.log(getAverage([45, 87, 98, 100, 86, 94, 67, 88, 94, 95]));



Which correctly prints the first log statement as 71.7, but instead of printing  85.4 below as my second console.log should, it adds the two together into 157.1. When I comment out the first console.log, then the second log statement works just fine. I am just unsure of what is adding the two return values together when both values are printed at the same time.

It's not console.log() doing it, it's the calls to getAverage(). If you do the first getAverage() without logging the result, you'll see the same effect.

You have the sum variable as a global and do not clear it at the start of your function.
Moving the sum declaration inside the function, fixes the problem.


function getAverage(scores) {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i=0; i< scores.length; i++) {
    sum +=  scores[i];
  }
  return (sum/ scores.length);
}

console.log(getAverage([92, 88, 12, 77, 57, 100, 67, 38, 97, 89]));
console.log(getAverage([45, 87, 98, 100, 86, 94, 67, 88, 94, 95]));




The scores variable being globally scoped doesn't matter, JavaScript uses the local scores variable instead. What does matter is the sum variable being globally scoped. In your version, you changed sum to be locally scoped, allowing for the function getAverage to properly run and return a valid value every time it is called.

@BrodBlox09, that is exactly what I was thinking, that is what my code reflects, but somehow my brain hiccuped and my description says the wrong thing. Thanks for catching that. I fixed the description.
